# css issue while using multi select and scroll feature in datatables

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am using datatable's multi select feature and scrollX and scrollY with various other features as well. But the features particularly multiselect and sScrollX, sScrollY seems to conflict eachother.

---

## multiselect only

http://postimg.org/image/z55uqsbxd/

---

While using multifilter with scroll feature, the width of multiselect textbox seem to shift right. With more than 40 columns, the UI gets worse.

## multiselect with scrollY

http://postimg.org/image/palnmlfnb/

---

I dig into the rendered html with firebug and found that,
1. In multiselect only, there are no styles for width

```
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
<span class="filter_column filter_text">
```

2. But after using scroll X and Y feature i.e. ( sScrollX, sScrollY), styles appears

```
<tr>
<th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 17px;">
<span class="filter_column filter_text">
```

And the culprit here seems to be the style="width: XXpx;" which is being rendred by the javascript, for each 'th'

```
element.style {
    width: XXpx;
}
```

## Note: XX above refers to two digit number, e.g 14

I even tried to use css feature overflow:auto; for the entire table which works perfectly but now the scroll bar is for the entire table. But I also have another features like tableTools and Colvis feature at the top which comes under vertical scroll bar as well. So this was not a solution.

Please shed some light my friends.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. There's a bug with how the horizontal padding is added in the header cells versus the body cells. I'm looking through my code, but didn't note what I did to fix it. Try eliminating the fixed width and/or setting the horizontal padding to 0.

**UPDATE:**
Went back and dug into this. I ended up putting no horizontal padding on the  tags, and then wrapped the content in them in spans, and applied the horizontal padding to that. So effectively...

```
<th>
  <span>Column heading</span>
</th>
```

and then for the CSS

```
th {
  padding: 3px 0;
}

th span {
  padding: 0px 15px;
}
```

And then to generate the proper HTML you'll need a callback to wrap the headings.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnColHeads = function( oSettings ) {
  return this.each( function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this
      .parents('.dataTables_wrapper:first')
      .find('.dataTables_scrollHead')
        .find('th.sorting_asc, th.sorting_desc, th.sorting')
          // adds the dom objects
          .each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            if ( $this.find('span').length < 1 ) {
              $this.wrapInner('<span />');
            }
          });
  });
});

$.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  "fnInitComplete": function() {
    this.fnColHeads();
  }
});
```

This is all simplified versions of my own code. Let me know if it works or you spot any errors.

Comment: Ya I tried to override the width by "width:0px !important" for the table but its not helping either. Could you please have a look, if you have found the solution. Giving me a headache for 2days straight.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I missed the notification that you had gotten back.